# How to link Google Drive API with multiple accounts using Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have successfully use the google drive api and was to able to upload files using python. The problem is I wanted to link it to another account. The same credentials file works for multiple accounts which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to link the project to another account, you have to create a project with that account and then use the credentials for the ***credentials.json*** file, also you will have to delete the ***token.pickle*** file.
[Set-up the credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user)

The ***credentials.json*** file is not supposed to work with multiple accounts, if you want multiple account to access the project you should set the authentication to [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).